# Input to LSTM network tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a time series of length t (x0, ...,xt) each of the xi is a d-dimension vector i.e. xi=(x0i, x1i, ...., xdi). Thus my input X is of shape [batch_size, d]

The input for the tensorflow LSTM should be of size [batchSize, hidden_size]. 
My question is how should i input my time series to the LSTM. One possible solution that i thought of is to have additional weight matrix, W, of size [d,hidden_size] and to input the LSTM with X*W + B.

Is this correct or should i input something else to the netwoרk?

Thanks

Comment: When discussing X you mention batch_size, but for the LSTM you mention batchSize. Are these the same thing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your intuition is correct; what you need (and what you have described) is an embedding to translate your input vector to the dimension of your LSTM's input. There are three primary ways that I know of to accomplish that.

- You could do this manually with an additional weight matrix `W` and bias vector `b` as you described.
- You could create the weight matrix and bias vectors automatically using the `linear()` function [from TensorFlow's rnn_cell.py library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L668). Then pass the output of that linear layer as the input of your LSTM when you create your LSTM via the `rnn_decoder()` function [in Tensorflow's seq2seq.py library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L36) or otherwise.
- Or you could have Tensorflow create this embedding and hook it up to the inputs of your LSTM  automatically, by creating the LSTM via the `embedding_rnn_decoder()` function at line 141 of the same seq2seq library. (If you trace through the code for this function without any optional arguments, you'll see that it is simply creating a linear embedding layer for the input as well as the LSTM and hooking them together.)

Unless you need access to the individual components that you're creating for some reason, I would recommend the third option to keep your code at a high level.

Comment: Does that third solution actually work in this case? Can you use embedding_rnn_decoder() for a sparse, but multidimensional input tensor? It looks like that function will lookup an embedding given a one-dimensional integer or one-hot-encoding, but not a way to just changed the dimensionality of an input vector using a weight matrix.

Comment: what is the state of the art method or what is the recommended method? thx!